# Cannot convert to Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have lists within lists

```
label_list =
[['a'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['a', 'd'],
 ['a'],
 ['a'],
```

that i want to paste in excel but it keeps showing an error: Cannot Convert ["a"]to Excel

Below is my sample code:

I want each list to start from column D, where a list has more than 1 element- I want the element to flow to the next columns same row.

```
label_row = 2

for label in label_list:
        no_oflabels = len(label)
        if no_oflabels == 1:
            ws.cell(row=label_row, column=start_column+4).value = label
            label_row += 1
        else:
            for element in label:
                ws.cell(row=created_row, column=start_column+4).value = element
                start_column += 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you have only one element, you try to insert not only the element into your excel sheet, but the whole list. There is a subtle difference between those two things. What you want to insert is `label[0]` rather than `label`, making the line read:

```
...
ws.cell(row=label_row, column=start_column+4).value = label[0]
...
```

However, as the code is written, this is also doing much more than needed. There is no meaning in having a special case for a single element. It is perfectly valid to loop over a list with a single element. Thus, it is sufficient to run the `else:` clause:

```
label_row = 2

for label in label_list:
        no_oflabels = len(label)
        for element in label:
            ws.cell(row=created_row, column=start_column+4).value = element
            start_column += 1
```

I see another potential error in your code, though. I *think* that your intention is to align your rows to the same column. In that case, you have to reset `start_column` prior to each run of the inner loop, or (probably better) use another offset variable. This can be done with `enumerate`, giving you code looking something like (if you indeed want to add 4 to your `start_column`):

```
label_row = 2

for label in label_list:
        no_oflabels = len(label)
        for offset, element in enumerate(label):
            ws.cell(row=created_row, column=start_column+4+offset).value = element
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! This works great!! Thank you for the detailed explanation